# Ajax error 401 in production, but works local

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core, iis-10, kestrel

I have a Net Core application that started to present a few problems lately. It was working just fine, but recently my Ajax calls will throw a 401 error.

That just happens in the production server, running on localhost everything works just fine. Also, this appears to be happening randomly, so the same ajax call will sometimes throw this error and sometimes it won't.

After digging a lot I noticed a few differences between the headers of those calls when they run local and when they run on the production server, but I don't know exaclty how to interpret and solve them.

Could you help me? None of those calls are to an external API/resource, they all call the page the user is currently on in the app itself.

I'll add the screenshot of the console showing the difference between headers. On the left is the one running local and I've used exactly the same data on both tests.

The production server is running IIS 10, if that's relevant.[image]

[image]

Comment: It is pointless to compare headers at this moment. Back to the basics, what's your production environment? Exposing Kestrel directly to the internet? On which operating system?

Comment: We need detailed error subcode like 401.2 for more information. Can you also try with IIS on the production Server? If it is Linux, Apache and Nginx also support asp.net core website. You can reference this to diagnose with Kestre: [Logging and diagnostics in Kestrel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel/diagnostics?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Comment: @LexLi I don't have much information on the specifics of the production server, because the app is hosted on a hosting company. The info I have at the moment is that is a shared server running windows and using IIS 10. What kind of information would I need to provide?

Comment: @samwu how do I get the detailed subcode of the 401 error? I'm logging everything on the "error" from the ajax call and it only shows "401", with no subcode. According to my hosting company the website is running on windows and IIS 10.

Comment: While you claimed the production is IIS 10, the actual header said a different story (HTTP server header was `Kestrel`). Again, too much is unknown right now, and I don't believe anyone can help much without touching the actual environments.

Comment: You can use [failed request tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-failed-request-tracing-to-trace-rewrite-rules) to view detailed error information.